# QGraphicsRectItem's signal itemChange not generating on drag

Tags: qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have made a custom class derived from QGraphicsRectItem.

```
class CornerPoint : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
  public:
  CornerPoint(QPointF centre);

 enum { Type = UserType + 1 };

 int type() const{ return Type; }

QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value);

public slots:

void updatePosition(QPointF);

};
```

CPP File

```
 CornerPoint::CornerPoint(QPointF centre): QGraphicsRectItem(NULL)
 {
    setPos(55,22);
    setRect(0,0,99,99);
 }

  QVariant CornerPoint::itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    std::cout << "Change is" << change << std::endl;

     if( QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange == change && scene())
     {
        std::cout << "New values " << value.toPointF().x() << value.toPointF().y() << std::endl;
     }

    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
 }
```

I have made these objects selectable and moveable. But when I drag them, I dont receive the signal for position change of this rectangle. All I receive are the signals with value 4 (`ItemSelectedChange`) and 14 (`ItemSelectedHasChanged`).

[This post](http://aladagemre.blogspot.in/2010/06/qgraphicsitemitemchange-event-and.html) says that I need to enable some flags. But I can't find any example of any one doing this, and using these flags is giving errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crap.

I just had to enable this flag :

`setFlag(GraphicsItemFlag::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);`